# Custom Annotation to Format Field Based on Another Field

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I have a Spring Boot 2 project and need to format a field in an entity based on another field. The 'name' field in the entity below needs the format of 'name' + "(Invalid)" if 'active' is false otherwise if true then "(Invalid)" needs to be removed. This example is the simplest case. In reality there are about 30 classes that need this logic applied. Each one has an 'active' field but the 'name' could be anything.

```
public class Entity {
  private String name;
  private boolean active;

  // getters and setters
}
```

I have thought about two options:

1. Hack the setActive(boolean active) method to append or remove "(Invalid)" based on the 'active' value. I don't want to do this because it would be more than 30 classes to hack.
2. Create a custom annotation that will apply the logic to add or remove "(Invalid)" to the 'name' field.
3. Another option that I am missing.

Is it possible to create a custom annotation that will do this? If so how?

In my research I have figured out how to set the value based on reflection. And create a custom annotation. I am confused about how to get Spring to see it and when it would execute it.

Comment: what do you want to use Entity for?

Comment: @clevertension those are database objects